# Does Yelp "expose" business reviews via consumable feed?

Tags: yelp

Does Yelp expose reviews for a given business (via an RSS feed or some other format)? I’d love to pull this content into a “testimonials” area of a website I maintain for a local business.

Would love to have URL to user image, short lead-in to review, rating, date of review, and URL to full review.

Comment: I used the Yelp contact form to ask a close variation of this question. Posting Q/A pair here for benefit of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Nick Griffen, Yelp Partner Relations:

> The API provides some of those things (a few review excerpts, rating,
>   date, means to link to full review):
>   http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started/what_you_get
>
> ...generally we're protective of our content and I think the decision not
>   to expose a stream of reviews via RSS is influenced by that protective
>   stance.